# Can't touch UITextField after scrolling

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uitextfield

I have a ViewController setup like so:

```
-View
--scrollView
---contentView (UIView)
```

All of my content is in the contentView. Most of the content is UITextFields that I added programmatically to fashion a form-like setup. I can touch the text fields when I first enter the View Controller to bring up the keyboard to type on them, however, as soon as I scroll down (so I can see the rest of the textfields on the view) none of them respond to touch, even the ones that I could originally see and interact with when I first entered the view controller. There is, however, one button that I added from the storyboard that will continuously accept touch events even after scrolling, but the textfields I added programmatically will not.

I am not sure what code to place here and I don't have the first clue as to where to look for this sort of situation. Any help would be awesome, this is my first app so things are coming along slowly. Thanks so much in advance.

[Code Here](https://gist.github.com/nmcdonaldd/e0ad2ae9886e49a5d1d8)

Comment: Place some log statements in your touch events. What classes are receiving touch events? First step is finding who is getting the touch events. Put a listener in all possible classes.

Comment: I only have a `view controller.swift` that is handling everything for this view controller. So I would assume it is handling the touch events? Where else would I look to put log statements?

Comment: A view controller holds a view (which likely has many subviews). Each view handles touch events itself. It sounds like you really need to work on the basics. I suggest you look over the getting started guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457

Comment: I understand how the ViewController works. That page doesn't really help me figure out the text fields touch issues. This is literally an app with one view so far. It is outlined as above. I feel like it should be really simple, but every time I scroll, the textfields become unusable.

Comment: You should make your way through all of the pages I linked to you, its good when you are getting started. And you are correct, it is a simple solution except when its not! But more to the point you need to understand  how views work. Views intercept touch events. You need to put touch event listeners on the view(s) you want to have receive event. So the first question is: does my intended view get the touch event? Clearly not. The next question is: What view IS getting the touch event. You follow? You need to put logs on ALL potential intercepting views and see whats swallowing the touch event

Comment: I don't mean to be ignorant but I'm reading through the pages and I can't see how they would help me here. I can't figure out how to intercept the touch events so I can log some information about the touches.

Comment: Since I assumed you added touch events I assumed you already knew how. This is the page on touch events: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html 

In your comment you said "I only have a view controller.swift that is handling everything for this view controller. So I would assume it is handling the touch events?" which indicated you don't seem to understand the nature of viewcontrollers vs views. So the first doc is to help you. The second part of my comment addressed your view events, logging the touch

Comment: For your UITextField specifically https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/

Look at the bottom. The notifications section. Do you know how delegates work? The os is going to fire events to your delegate, that's going to be your UITextField. You can log statements in the `UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditingNotification` callback. If thats not firing that's your first hint that somethings not right! Maybe there's a view on top of it, or maybe there's a problem with your delegate setup.

Comment: I did not add touch events. In other simple apps I've made alongside tutorials, there were no scrolling at all. Just adding the UITextField as a subview to the contentView worked. And I assumed thats how it would work with a contentView that is inside a scrollView. As far as the documentation, I can't figure out where it says anything about handling touch events across views and view controllers so that's where my confusion is stemming from. I also do not know much about delegates or what they do, how they work, and how I would use one to help me here. ill try to take a look at the docs.

Comment: In future questions, I suggest you post some code. Its very hard for people to give specific answers based on vague explanations. Clear code + clear explanation gives you the best chance of getting an answer. Good luck.

Comment: I just don't really know what code to place. It is pretty trivial, or so I thought. I just had a View, then a scrollView inside that, then a contentView inside that. Then in my code, it's literally just `self.contentView.addSubview(textField)`

Comment: @Aggressor, I have added touchRecognizers along with logs to concluded that if I do not scroll, the contentView handles all of the touches. However, once I scroll, the scrollView handles all of the touches and doesn't hand them off to the contentView subview. I am lost now on how I would send those off to the subview contentView.

Comment: I can't help unless there's code.

Comment: @Aggressor I added the link to code. Anything you think you could help me out with? Thanks a lot so far

Comment: Its a start,  but I don't have enough information. You haven't told me what events are firing, and I don't know how you setup your storyboard sizing (personally I never use storyboards as it adds coding redundancy and bugs).

Comment: What do you mean "events are firing". I used gestureRecognizers to log out which views are picking up the taps if that's what you mean. The contentView which is linked to Storyboard is just bounded to the size of the whole entire view in the Storyboard.

Comment: At this stage I don't think I can be of further help. Best of luck.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your advice so far.